# Set UFW before.rules without server restart

Tags: server, ufw

I use UFW on my Ubuntu server. Unfortunately there are no rules in UFW to port-forward to another machine. 
What you need to do is edit /etc/ufw/before.rules and put routing commands there, for example

```
# nat Table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from eth0 through eth1.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p udp --dport 10090 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.202:22
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 10090 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.202:22
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:443
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p udp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:443
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 57626 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2:57626
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p udp --dport 57626 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2:57626
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:3306
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p udp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.200:3306

COMMIT
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to run new forwarding rules without restarting the server, which I hate to do very much.
So please help me, is there a way?

Comment: I think I've tried every answer in this, and couldn't find a solution, short of rebooting (which did work).  :'(  I'd love to see a better answer to this.  Strangely, it seemed like the rules were in place after some of these answers (as indicated by `iptables -t nat -L`), but the packets I cared about (ICMP) weren't being masqueraded (but rather being forwarded without NAT, and thus not returned).  Here's hoping an answer can be found.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

```
sudo service ufw restart
```

Comment: As I understand it, this is wrong. As in won't even load the new rules. See [my question](http://askubuntu.com/q/660972/289003) and [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/881137) (which has been marked as won't fix). Can anyone else confirm this actually working after changing rules in `/etc/before.rules`?

Comment: @Nateowami This solution works fine for me.

Comment: @MattBorja What version of Ubuntu and ufw? I really don't know much in this area; I've just been going on the bug report which basically said this was intended behavior, and my own experience.

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 20.04. Added a DNAT rule to port-forward, which worked after reloading, but after removing the rule, the port still gets forwarded.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as it looks:

```
sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Well

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/before.rules
```

might work.

Comment: `/etc/ufw/before.rules` is not a valid iptables format, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, following works on Ubuntu 20.04.

Flush chains and restart ufw:

```
sudo /usr/lib/ufw/ufw-init flush-all
sudo service ufw restart
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
/etc/init.d/ufw restart
```

[**Source**](http://ndthuan.com/2011/12/how-to-apply-ufw-before-rules-without-restarting-the-server/)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sudo service ufw reload
```

Comment: @karel `reload` is not the same as `restart`.

Comment: This does not work.