# Port forwarding with UFW

Tags: firewall, iptables, ufw

I realize UFW is mainly just for enabling/disabling access on particular ports, but I'm trying to forward one port to another. I want any connection to port 1724 to be forwarded to 1723.

The file `/etc/default/ufw` already has `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`. And I believe I need to uncomment `net/ipv4/ip_forward=1` in `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`. Finally I need to edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules` to add an iptables rule.

And here is where I get lost because I can't find any documentation for this file. Where do I add the rule? And how exactly?

In particular:

- On exactly which line do I add the rule?
- Do I put anything before or after it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add before filter section in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`(top of file):

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1724 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1723
COMMIT
```

These rules will then need to be reloaded; simply disabling and re-enabling ufw or running `ufw reload` is not sufficient. The simplest solution is to reboot, otherwise you can use one of the workarounds mentioned in [Launchpad bug #881137](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/881137).

Comment: I added that to the top, saved, ran `sudo service ufw restart`, ran `sudo ufw allow tcp/1724`, but when I `nmap` the server it shows no connectivity on port `1724`. Any ideas?

Comment: Tray to make connection and follow traffic with `tcpdump`.

Comment: I ran `netstat -lntu` on the server and it lists 1723 but not 1724. So I highly doubt tcpdump would be able to turn anything up.

Comment: `tcpdump` can not solve problem but can tell us what happens when you tray to connect. Please try.

Comment: On the server I ran `sudo tcpdump -nnvvS -i eth0 src <CLIENT_IP> and port 1724`. Then on the client I ran `wget <SERVER_HOSTNAME>:1724`. Here's a sampling of what I got: `<CLIENT_IP>.50302 > <SERVER_IP>.1724: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5cad (correct), seq 1480796871:1480796985, ack 4563064, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4864530 ecr 1655545615], length 114`. What should I be looking for? (I don't actually have an HTTP server running on 1723 or 1724, but I figured any TCP traffic would work. `pptpd` is running on 1723).

Comment: Ok, if you hit server on `port 1724` with any `tcp` traffic from client, server accept traffic, then fw to `port 1723` and establish connection ..., this is it or I missed something?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I want to access the service on another port.

Comment: Ok, we do not understand each other. What happend  whn you try `telnet server_ip 1724` from client to server. Connection is refused?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27376/discussion-between-nateowami-and-2707974).